# Enable JavaScript capabilities

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I am trying to open one of ofline HTML page for which I am getting message as

The internet browser you are using is either JavaScript incapable or has it's JavaScript capabilities disabled. Please access this page with a JavaScript capable internet browser

I check Tools->Content setting , javascript is enabled for my IE9 browser. Still I am facing this issue.

Some time for same page I get message like -

Your Security Settings have blocked a local application from running.

Suggest me a workaround to resolve this issue.

Comment: Hmm.. this doesn't seem to be a programming issue. Am I wrong? Are you the author of the page or are you just trying to view it?

Comment: Can you please provide the code where the JS is called? Maybe it's doing more than just calling the JS code.

Comment: It's probably the browser's cross-site scripting protection. You can't load remote javascript into a local page. So if you're opening `file:///path/to/page.html`, and it's trying to include a remote JS file, then yes, that will fail.

Comment: I am not author of HTML page. This HTML page refers to the help files provided with softwares. @Spudley yes I am trying to file like below path C:\Program Files\NX\NXdoc\Index.html

Answer (score 1):

Internet Explorer -> Internet Options -> Advanced -> Allow Active Content to run in files on My Computer.  Make sure that is checked.  Must restart IE if you change this.

Comment: @glitnerj0- I tried this workaround but didn't helped I got error message as - Your Security Settings have blocked a local application from running

Comment: This answer is generally correct, as it relates to the disabling of JavaScript in local web pages. It sounds like your web page is also trying to do more than JavaScript, and is blocked by security settings which were probably introduced in IE7. This question doesn't belong on StackOverflow; try SuperUser instad.

Answer (score 0):

The page with blocked JavaScript may be in your zone for restricted sites (Internet Options, Security tab). JavaScript and other active scripting may be en- or disabled separately for each zone.

Comment: it is not site I am trying to access. It is just a offline HTML page which has search capabilities like in other help documents. I have all required files stored in one directory from where I am opening this HTML file - C:\Program Files\NX\NXdoc\Index.html